# Axios POST working in Node.js but not Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, twilio, node-modules

So I have a package with a function that uploads a file to Twilio:

```
const FD = require('form-data');
const axios = require('axios');

   async function createFunctionResource(serviceUid, functionUid, client){

    let collect_file = "Hello World"

    let url = `https://serverless-upload.twilio.com/v1/Services/${serviceUid}/Functions/${functionUid}/Versions`

    let form = new FD();
    collect_file = "test"

    form.append("Path", "collect");
    form.append("Visibility", "public");
    form.append("Content", collect_file, "collect.js");
    form.append("contentType", "application/javascript");

    await axios.post(url, form,  {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${client.accountSid}:${client.password}`).toString('base64'),
        ...form.getHeaders(),
    },
    })

}
```

This works completely fine in node.js and it gets uploaded with the message "Hello World" in the file.

I'm trying to put this into an electron app so I preload this package in preload.js with nodeIntegration set to true but whenever I try to upload a file I get:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

With the error response being:

```
{"message":"No file attached to request","code":70002,"user_error":true,"http_status_code":400,"params":{}}
```

Does preloading a package make it act exactly the same as it does in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

Even though you may try and preload a package with axios hoping it runs in a node environment, requests are done under XHR (browser).

To fix this you must specify the adapter to be HTTP by adding `adapter: require('axios/lib/adapters/http')`

```
    await axios.post(url, form,  {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${client.accountSid}:${client.password}`).toString('base64'),
        ...form.getHeaders(),
    },
    adapter: require('axios/lib/adapters/http'),
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can u add cotent-type in headers section and check .

"content-type": "application/json"